# How to find this two-variables limit of $f$ as $(x,y)$ approaches to $(0,0)$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I am trying to evaluate the limit $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{2x^6-y^{10}}{x^2-y^3}$$

I have seen that both the reiterated limits are zero. Moreover, I have evaluated the limit by different curves such as $y=x^2$ and the limit equals zero as well.

However, the polar coordinates $$\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{r^4(2\cos^6(\theta)-r^4\sin^{10}(\theta))}{\cos^2(\theta)-r\sin^3(\theta)}$$ make me think that the limit does not exist because it depends on the $\cos^2\theta$ factor, but I don't know how to prove it or which curve to use.

Comment: The problematic curve is $x^2 = y^3$. It passes through $(0, 0)$ and the value of expression approaches $\pm\infty$, when $(x, y)$ approaches this curve. Hence limit does not exist.

Comment: @D.Dmitriy But the function is not defined there, isn't it? As far as I am concerned, when you calculate the limit you can go only through the domain of that function. In this case, the curve $x^2=y^3$, although passes through $(0,0)$ is not in the domain. I think I have found a curve that proves that the limit does not exist because, taking $x^2=y^3+y^9$, $f(x,y)=2(1+y^6)^3-y$ that has limit $2 \neq 0$.

Comment: Can't you take $x=(y+\epsilon)^{1.5}$ and then let $(y,\epsilon)\to(0,0)$.  Shoule be enough to do it from the right, i.e. $\to(0+,0+)$ so that extracting roots is simpler.

Comment: @LostinSpace, well I have assumed that those curves that maintain the function defined. Is it like this or the curve proposed by Dmitriy is valid too? And then, my proposal is correct?

Comment: I wrote a solution and hope it helps @UlyssesJA

Comment: @UlyssesJA What's important, is that $f$ goes to infinity in the neighborhood of this curve. Any neighborhood of the $(0, 0)$ intersects this curve, which means any neighborhood of $(0, 0)$ contains arbitrary large values. This is the intuition. To show it concretely, you take some convenient sequence of points that approaches both curve $x^2=y^3$ and point $(0, 0)$, moreover this sequence should approach the curve in some sense "quick enough", compared to how "quick" it approaches $(0, 0)$. Your sequence $x^2 = y^3 + y^9$ fits this criteria, as well as others posted in this thread.

Comment: Okay, thanks all of you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

$$L=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{2x^6-y^{10}}{x^2-y^3}$$

Note that:

$$x^6-y^9=(x^2-y^3)(x^4+x^2y^3+y^6)$$

So we have:
$$L=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}2(x^4+x^2y^3+y^6)+\frac{2y^9-y^{10}}{x^2-y^3}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{y^9(2-y)}{x^2-y^3}$$

Let $x=y^{3/2}+y^{10}$

$$L=\lim_{y \to 0^+}\frac{y^9(2-y)}{2y^{23/2}+y^{20}}=\lim_{y \to 0^+}\frac{(2-y)}{2y^{5/2}+y^{11}}\to\infty$$

Answer (score -1):

Consider the sequence
$(\frac{1}{ n},0)\to(0,0)$

Then $f(\frac{1}{n},0)=\frac{1}{n^4}\to 0 $

Again the sequence $(\sqrt{\frac{n^2+1}{ n^3}},\frac{1}{ \sqrt[3]n})\to(0,0)$

But $\begin{align}f(\sqrt{\frac{n^2+1}{ n^3}},\frac{1}{ \sqrt[3]n})&=\frac{\frac{2(n^2+1)^3}{n^6}-\frac{1}{n^3\sqrt[3]n{}}}{\frac{1}{n^3}}\\&=2(1+\frac{1}{n^2}) ^3-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]n}
 \end{align}$

Hence $f(\sqrt{\frac{n^2+1}{ n^3}},\frac{1}{ \sqrt[3]n})\to 2$

Hence $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{2x^6-y^{10}}{x^2-y^3}$ doesn't exists.